# JQuery - Detect dimension of screen in cm/inches or alternative for displaying on mobile platforms

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have looked through all the information that I have been able to. As far as I can tell, it appears as if there is no way to detect the dimensions of a screen in cm/inches using jquery. I was wanting to do this because on mobile phones and tablets, the resolution is great enough that it wants to show my website, but make the text extremely small. Is there a way to solve this, or possibly find an alternative way to tell it to display differently using jquery on mobile platforms.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to set the viewport on your website:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: How does that work, how do I access that information in JQuery to tell my page to display differently? Or does it just automatically scale the page?

Comment: It will just automatically scale it

Comment: If you need to adjust any styles specifically for mobile, you can use media queries in you css. There's no need to use jquery.